# Fetching and loading external images in JSON data via AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, dom, cross-domain

I have an application that retrieves script contents, script sources, images, and links hosted in different domains.  The ajax request itself is not cross-domain but the JSON data sent over has links to various cross-domain script tags and image links.  Once the payload arrives, depending on the type of each resource, I execute the script if it is script content or add a script node to the DOM.

All this works fine.  However, images are not displayed by the browser even if I am setting an image element and adding the src attribute to the link from AJAX.

I have disabled ad blocker and tracking blocker.  Are there browser restrictions in place?  For additional information, the application is an Angular 7 application.

Comment: Hard to digest all this without any code references

Comment: `I feel there should be no browser restrictions doing this` - what about server restrictions? i.e. the server you're "borrowing" images from?

Comment: editing the question, you said that you aren't even sure if the image actually exists...check that first!  Then edit my edit with some of your actual code doing this.